# Picture with inconcistent sizes object-fit not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a portfolio website with HTML and CSS. for every portfolio item you click in on you come to a page with this structure but with different content in the tiles depending on the project. the structure or the nature of the content is always the same though, hence, always a picture in the first tile, always a bullet list in the second and always leaping text through the p tag in the third.

I've tried reasoning with chatgpt which made me add some !important disclaimers and change the object-fit from cover to contain but no change.... I expected the first and second child to stand on the same rows vertically next to each other while seeing the third child beneath them.

What might be the issue? The portfolio item working contains a 1080x1080px png. the other two not working is a 360x800 png and a 940x1062 jpg. So I am a bit confused...

```css
#digiHighlights .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

#digiHighlights .tile {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#digiHighlights .tile img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#digiHighlights .tile:nth-child(1),
#digiHighlights .tile:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

#digiHighlights .tile:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 4;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

#digiHighlights {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5% 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#digiHighlights p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#digiHighlights b {
  font-family: 'PPMonumentBlack', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #bffda3;
  color: #333;
}

#digiHighlights ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#digiHighlights ul li {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#digiHighlights ul li:before {
  content: '•';
  color: #bffda3;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="digiHighlights">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080" alt="Digilock - WireFrame Locked Bike">
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h2>DigiLock - A smart bike lock</h2>
      <h3>Rapid prototyping: UX and System Architecture Design</h3>
      <p><b>We delivered:</b></p>
      <ul>
        <li>A hi-fi Figma Prototype</li>
        <li>User Stories and Scenarios</li>
        <li>Use cases</li>
        <li>Conceptual model</li>
        <li>Sequence diagrams</li>
        <li>Activity Diagrams</li>
        <li>Exequation environment map</li>
        <li>A database scheme</li>
        <li>Requirements specification</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <p>During 8 weeks, we developed the UX and the overall system architecture design for a digital bike lock. The project was executed together with a team as part of a series of university examinations and received the highest grade.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please revise the demo above to show the problem. Also clarify what "breadtext" might be. I fixed your other spelling issues, but that one eludes me.

Comment: @isherwood Breadtext is an obscure slang in writing/typography for the main content of your work, as far as I know. A synonym would be 'copy' in marketing or just 'text content' for other fields/subjects.

Comment: @isherwood in what way do you want me to revise the demo? and with the demo you mean th code snippets? should i add the whole code for the html page and the full css document?

Comment: @TylerH youre right. although in my native language is not so obscure so i just made a direct translation oupsie

Comment: If it already shows the problem, great. I don't see what you're describing, though, or I don't understand.